# NICE Framework - is there a link between Tasks and KSAs?

Tags: nist

In the [NICE Cybersecurity Workforce Framework](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-181.pdf) document there are 1,007 Tasks and 1,180 KSAs - is there any explanation of the direct links between the Tasks and KSAs? (or any database)

In the document, there is no connection between Tasks and KSAs - the Tasks that each Work Role is responsible for and the KSAs required for each role are listed, but no direct Tasks-to-KSA connection. Is there anywhere that explains which Tasks and which KSAs are connected? And, furthermore is there any database that is publicly available that allows the analysis of the relationships?

I feel like somewhere there must be this information because each Work Role is simply a combination of Tasks and all the KSAs required for each Work Role must have been chosen based on them being needed to carry out the tasks.

NICE provides a *Work Role Detail Listing* which states the Tasks and the KSAs that correspond to each of the 54 **Work Roles**.

For example the **Work Role** *Authorizing Official* < **Specialty Area** *Risk Management* < **Category** *Securely Provision* has 5 Tasks, 39 'Knowledges', 2 Skills and 11 Abilities. 'Knowledges' 0001 - 0006 are common to all **Work Roles**, however after that there is no direct connection between Tasks and specific KSAs - I think that this breakdown would be the most useful.

I appreciate that there will not be a 1-to-1 connection, but a database that allowed you to search all the KSAs required for a certain Tasks, all the Tasks that a KSA contributes to, how many different work roles each Task and KSA correspond to.

Does anyone have, or has anyone come across a document or database where the data allows these connections to be analyzed?

Comment: Tasks and KSAs don't have the kind of relationship that can be mapped like that.

Comment: Hello schroeder, thanks for taking the time to read my question and for adding the flag - but, if someone had the information formatted correctly surely you could search, for example, the KSAs that are always required for certain tasks and from that you could build a relationship?